# vimrc specify more than 1 file extensions in autocmd

Tags: vimrc, autocmd

I know a little bit of `autocmd` and use it for few things. Currently, I have

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.inc set filetype=sql
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.tbl set filetype=sql
```

Reading the man page, the general syntax is

```
:autocmd [group] {events} {file_pattern} [nested] {command}
```

I would like to know, whether I can combine the above 2 statements in a single lin i.e. how can we specify more that one file extension in the *file_pattern* section? The man page doesn't say about this, but I believe it can be comma or space separated. Any hints?

Answer (score 6):

> I believe it can be comma or space separated

No, the file pattern list must be comma separated with no spaces:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.tbl,*.inc setf sql
```

Beware that injecting a space will not result in an error, and the autocmd will still apply properly to patterns before the space, but the ones after that will be ignored.

Comment: I believe it's strictly comma separated and there cannot be a space in the list. This means `*.tbl,*.inc` works, but `*.tbl <space> *.inc` or `*.tbl, <space> *.inc` will not (at least with vim v8.1)

Comment: Thanks -- I'm surprised I'd would post this without having confirmed spaces were okay, since looking through my current conf files I don't use spaces, and a quick test demonstrates they are no good.

Comment: We're all here to help :-)